# Is `std::list::splice(std::const_iterator pos, std::list&& other)` guaranteed to leave `other` empty?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stl, c++14

Is `std::list::splice(std::const_iterator pos, std::list&& other)` guaranteed to leave `other` empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed for [`std::list::splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice).

(emphasis mine)

> 1) Transfers all elements from other into `*this`. The elements are inserted before the element pointed to by `pos`. **The container `other` becomes empty after the operation**. The behavior is undefined if other refers to the same object as `*this`.

From the standard, [[list.ops]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/list.ops#4):

(emphasis mine)

> Effects: Inserts the contents of `x` before `position` and **`x` becomes empty**. Pointers and references to the moved elements of `x` now refer to those same elements but as members of `*this`. Iterators referring to the moved elements will continue to refer to their elements, but they now behave as iterators into `*this`, not into `x`.

Comment: Why does the R-valued `other` version of the function exist?

Comment: @Museful Otherwise you can't call it with rvalue list?

Comment: But can't the l-valued reference argument bind to an rvalue?

Comment: @Museful No, rvalues can't be bound to lvalue-reference.

Comment: Oh yes I was thinking of *const* lvalue references.

Comment: @Museful It can't be `const`; then we can't modify it (and make it empty).

Comment: Yes I understand that now

Answer (score 0):

Will the destination start as an empty list? Then you could [swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) the lists.

Otherwise if you're unsure you could [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) the source list into the destination list, and [clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/clear) the source list.